# Could not find Gcrypt and wireshark headers..CMake Error

Tags: c++, build, cmake, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I am trying to build and install [Whatsapp disector for Wireshark](https://github.com/davidgfnet/wireshark-whatsapp) in Ubuntu 12.04. I have wireshark and libgcrypt20 installed. When I try to run the

> cmake ..

commannd, I am facing the following error.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7e9P.jpg)

I assume that i have to set the include directory path of gcrypt and wireshark for the variables GCRYPT_INCLUDE_DIRS and WIRESHARK_INCLUDE_DIRS respectively. But I am unaware of how to get the location of the include directories.

Correct me if my understanding is wrong and help me resolve this issue..

Comment: According to [findWireshark.cmake](https://github.com/davidgfnet/wireshark-whatsapp/blob/master/cmake/FindWireshark.cmake), it uses `FIND_PATH( WIRESHARK_INCLUDE_DIRS epan/column-info.h PATH_SUFFIXES wireshark )` for set `WIRESHARK_INCUDE_DIRS` variable. You need to set this variable so, that `${WIRESHARK_INCLUDE_DIRS}/epan/column-info.h` will refer to the header file in the wireshark installation.

Comment: Alternatively, you can try to set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` **environment variable** to installation prefixes of your packages: `export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=<wireshark-install-prefix>;<gcrypt-install-prefix>`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @Tsyvarev. I understand the problem now. My question is, How/where can I find out the value that I need to set for GCRYPT_INCLUDE_DIRS and WIRESHARK_INCLUDE_DIRS. Thanks again :)

Comment: You need to find `column-info.h` file in your `wireshark` installation. If you install it via package manager, it should be a way for list files of the package. If you install it manually, check files under installation prefix you use. Or run installation step again, usualy it will print which prefix it uses or even which files it installs.